# reader with blank or null records

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Thought the code would catch empty records but it turns out it has not been and no error.

turns out my function always returns FALSE

```
Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim strQuery As String = "Select * FROM [UsersDataTbl] " & _
                   "WHERE [UserName] = """ & UserName & """"
        Dim comm As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strQuery, conn)
        Dim reader As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            If noNull(reader("StudentID") = "") _
            Or noNull(reader("LastName") = "") _
            Or noNull(reader("FirstName") = "") _
            Or noNull(reader("Affiliation") = "") Then
                BlankFields = True
            Else
                BlankFields = False
            End If
        End While
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
```

ADDED:
found my noNull method:

```
 Public Function noNull(ByRef o As Object) As String
    If (o Is Nothing) Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Return o.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: What's the code of noNull?

Comment: access DB - I'm checking for empty or null record?

Comment: try `isdbnull` instead of `noNull`

Comment: `If not isdbNull(reader("StudentID") = "") _`

Comment: error on both suggestions ...

Comment: Could you add the code of noNull method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

```
Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\yourDB.accdb;")
Dim cb As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 "
Dim dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = cb
con.Open()
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
   While dr.Read()
        If Not IsDBNull(dr("value1")) Then MessageBox.Show(dr("value1"))
    End While
con.Close()
```

Comment: I need to check if record is empty and/or Null - this seems to only check Null?

Comment: Thanks Orlando, I had to redo some of my DB connection as well to make the IsDBNull work, but that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I process recordfield values like this:

```
Dim iVal As Integer = NoNull(r.Fields("someintegerfield").Value, "0", False)


Public Function NoNull(ByVal uAny As Object, Optional ByVal uFillString As String = "", Optional ByVal uTreatDecimalNullAsNothing As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim sRet As String = String.Empty

    If Not Convert.IsDBNull(uAny) AndAlso Not uAny Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Assert(uAny.GetType.ToString <> "cField") 'checking if the argument is a "cField" helps me to check whether I passes "r.fields("somefield").value to this function, or if I forgot the ".value")

        sRet = uAny
    Else
        sRet = String.Empty
    End If

    If StrLen(sRet) = 0 Then
        If modStrings.StrLen(uFillString) > 0 Then
            sRet = uFillString
        End If
    End If

    If uTreatDecimalNullAsNothing Then
        If sRet = "0" Then
            sRet = uFillString
        End If
    End If

    Return sRet

End Function

Public Function StrLen(ByVal uString As String) As Integer

    If (Not uString Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not uString = "") Then
        Return uString.Length
    Else
        Return 0
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the `noNull` method is something like this

```
Public Function noNull(dbValue As Object) as Boolean
    if dbValue = DBNull.Value OrElse dbValue = "" Then
         return True
    else
         return False
    End If
End Function
```

Then you call it with

```
....
noNull(reader("LastName") = "")
....
```

This means that you compare the value of the `LastName` field to an Empty string and the result is a boolean True or False, but passing a Boolean value to `noNull` means that it will never be equal to an empty string or to a DBNull.Value and thus it will return always false

You need to call the method with

```
       If noNull(reader("StudentID")) _
        Or noNull(reader("LastName")) _
        Or noNull(reader("FirstName")) _
        Or noNull(reader("Affiliation")) Then
```

Or without the noNull method

```
       If reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("StudentID")) _
                        OrElse reader("StudentID") = ""  _
                        OrElse reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName")) _
                        OrElse reader("LastName") = ""
                        OrElse reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName")) _
                        OrElse reader("FirstName") = "" _
                        OrElse reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Affiliation")) _
                        OrElse reader("Affiliation") = "" Then
           BlankFields = True
      Else
           BlankFields = False
      End If
```

As you can see this is really ugly, so I suppose that a method like `noNull` iomplemented above could be useful in this context

**EDIT** Now, looking at the code of your `noNull` method then it is clear where is the error.
You should just change the parenthesis position.

```
If noNull(reader("StudentID")) = "" _
          Or noNull(reader("LastName")) = "" _
          Or noNull(reader("FirstName")) = "" _
          Or noNull(reader("Affiliation")) = "" Then
```

Comment: added noNull method to original post: